# fscanf not reading floats correctly

Tags: c, scanf

---This is a Homework question---

I'm having problems reading float values from a text file using fscanf.

Basically I'm trying to read float values from a file and store them in a dynamic array.
The input file has two floats per line. so a line might be "0.85 7.34" (w/o quotes). so I'm trying to use fscanf(fp, "%f %f", &coordinates[i], &coordinates[i++]) to read in the 2 float values. when i print it shows as 0.00000. Below is the code I wrote and the output it produces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv []) {

FILE * fp = fopen("nums", "r");

float *coordinates;
float *tmp;
int i = 0;
int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
coordinates = malloc(5*sizeof(float));

while (fscanf(fp,"%f %f", &coordinates[i], &coordinates[i++]) > 1)
{

  printf("iteration# %d | coord1 = %f coord2 = %f \n", i, &coordinates[i-1], &coordinates[i]);

  if (i >= ARRAY_SIZE)
  {
    tmp = realloc(coordinates, (i*2)*sizeof(float));
    coordinates = tmp;
    ARRAY_SIZE = i*2;
  }
  i++;
}

for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  printf("%f\n", &coordinates[i]);


return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
iteration# 1 | coord1 = 0.000000 coord2 = 0.000000 
iteration# 3 | coord1 = 0.000000 coord2 = 0.000000 
iteration# 5 | coord1 = 0.000000 coord2 = 0.000000 
iteration# 7 | coord1 = 0.000000 coord2 = 0.000000 
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: Careful. `fscanf(fp,"%f %f", &coordinates[i], &coordinates[i++])` is undefined behavior, because you're not guaranteed if `coordinates[i]` is evaluated before or after `coordinates[i++]`, so you could be mixing things up (since `i` may not be incremented when you think it is)! Order of evaluation of args is not specified.

Comment: so you mean i could be incremented before coordinates[i] is evaluated?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. Plus, you probably wanted `++i` instead of `i++` (assuming the arguments were evaluated in the order you wanted, which they're not). There's a difference in C between pre and post-increment. Actually, maybe what you really wanted was `i++` on both of them. But still, order of evaluation is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the "address of"-operator `&` with `printf`.  `fscanf` requires a pointer to the data so it knows can change the variables value, while printf does not.

Change:

```
printf("iteration# %d | coord1 = %f coord2 = %f \n", i, &coordinates[i-1], &coordinates[i]);
```

To:

```
printf("iteration# %d | coord1 = %f coord2 = %f \n", i, coordinates[i-1], coordinates[i]);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, I can't believe i spent so much time on such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
 while (fscanf(fp,"%f %f", &coordinates[i], &coordinates[i++]) > 1)
```

you're trying to use the value of `i` in `&coordinates[i]` and modify it in `&coordinates[i++]` without an intervening sequence point.  The behavior on doing so is *undefined*, and most likely won't be doing what you want.  Use `&coordinates[i+1]` for the second argument.  Note this means you'll have to update `i` in the loop with `i += 2` or similar.  Note that it's *not* guaranteed that `&coordinates[i]` is evaluated before `&coordinates[i++]`.

Second problem:

```
printf("%f\n", &coordinates[i]);
```

Again, you've invoked undefined behavior; you've told `printf` to expect a value of type `float`, but you're passing a value of type `float *`.  Lose the `&`.  `scanf` and `printf` are not symmetrical in this respect.

Head-scratchers:

You know there are going to be 2 values per line, but you start your array size at 5 (rather than 4 or 6 or 8).  You allow for resizing the array (correctly, I might add), but you've hardcoded a size of 8 for the print loop, rather than using the actual number of items read.